# MonthCalendar alternative for vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a KIOSK system with SMS function. The kiosk contents is the calendar of events of the school. I am currently using monthcalendar the default from VS but the problem is it's not presentable specially for a kiosk system that will be used by many people. I tried searching but i cant find any answer relevant to my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools | Extensions and Updates...` in Visual Studio's menu, then click `Visual Studio Gallery` under `Online`, and try searching there. I've found very good calendars for Windows 8/Modern there.

Also try `Tools | NuGet Package Manager | Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`. I've also found a good variety of controls there.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But can you name some of the good calendars you found in the VS gallery? I can't find one and most of them are trial version only.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. I was creating a Metro/Modern App, and  Perperuum UI Controls for Windows 8 worked perfectly for me. If you're developing for WPF, you might look at Xceed WPF Toolkit in the NuGet Gallery. There isn't another calendar in there, but there are a few other tools for dates and numbers.